# Visual Composer, page specific custom css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I encountered an issue with Visual Composer (VC) in Wordpress. I am building a website using Impreza theme where VC is included.

In my homepage, I have added the VC element "custom heading". The problem is that the background image is too bright/white, the heading is blending in with the background. I wanted to fix that with the text-shadow property but it did not work. ([myWebsite](http://toastmasters.be/capgemini/))

As you can see in the following picture, here is the process I followed.

[customHeading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IpzR.jpg)

1. is the setting button I clicked on to access the custom CSS file.
2. is the VC element I have added.

[customCSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98nGo.jpg) Here is the css code I have added in the custom css file.

[extraclass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1JNH.jpg) Here is the mention of the extra class in the VC element options.

With this additional customization, nothing happened on my homepage. the custom heading stays white with no outlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there is a `.`(dot) in your extra `custom head` class.

[image]

Try to remove `.` from your extra  `custom head` class.

Comment: -_- damned me. Thank you very much for your help it was the source of the issue indeed.